# Wordpress menu looks like a fail after update to 6.4.3

Tags: wordpress, menu

After I updated WordPress the menu looks really ugly on top right side. Is anyone else experiencing this?

[image: Example]

I tried to change the menu's appearance via block editor, I deleted the menu items and reentered them. The same thing happens every time...